# Start a function after a timeout

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, timeout

Edit: Someone told me to give some more code, to be better to understand. I try to make a feedback card, and after you click on "post", i want for you to have 10 seconds to press "Edit" to edit your feedback or it will restart as new. So in this way you can give more feedback in the same day.
When i press Edit, my function is still working, go after few seconds i got a new feedback card as new. I need to edit it when i press on edit and i need a new feedback card when i wait 10 seconds. I hope now you understand, i tried manny thing but i didn't get any solution.

I'm trying to display somethings in a special order, but my function cho starts at the same time as haha. Can somebody tell me what i did wrong? How can i delay cho function to start after haha?

Here is what i did so far:
Html:

```js
var btn= document.getElementById('btn1');
var post= document.getElementById('post');
var widget= document.getElementById('star-widget');
var editBtn= document.getElementById('exit');
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var y=document.getElementsByTagName("label");
var z;
function H(){
    widget.style.display="none";
    post.style.display="block";
    editBtn.onclick=()=>{
        widget.style.display="block";
        post.style.display="none";
        z=true;
        return false;
        
    }
    if(z==true){
    }else{
        console.log("Before setTimeout");
        setTimeout(function() {
            Haha();
        }, 1000);
        function Haha() {
          console.log("Start Haha");
          widget.style.display = "none";
          post.style.display = "block";
          z = false;
          setTimeout(function() {
            cho();
            setTimeout(function() {
              done();
            }, 1000);
          }, 1000);
        }
      function cho() {
        console.log("Start cho");
        widget.style.display = "block";
        post.style.display = "none";
        x[0].checked = false;
        x[1].checked = false;
        x[2].checked = false;
        x[3].checked = false;
        x[4].checked = false;
        y[0].checked = false;
        y[1].checked = false;
        y[2].checked = false;
        y[3].checked = false;
        y[4].checked = false;
        z = false;
      }
      function done(){
      console.log("After setTimeout");
      }         
    }  
}
```

```css
.container{
    width: 400px;
    background: #111;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container #star-widget input{
    display: none;
}
#star-widget label{
    font-size:40px;
    color: #444;
    padding: 10px;
    float:right;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
#star-widget input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover, #star-widget input:not(:checked) ~ label:hover ~ label{
    color: #fd4;

}
#star-widget input:checked ~ label{
    color: #fd4;
}
#star-widget input#rate-5:checked ~ label{
    color: #fe3;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 20px #952;
}
#star-widget input#rate-4:checked ~ label{
    color: #fd4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 20px #952;
}
#star-widget input#rate-3:checked ~ label{
    color: #fc4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 20px #952;
}
#star-widget input#rate-2:checked ~ label{
    color: #fb4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 20px #952;
}
#star-widget input#rate-1:checked ~ label{
    color: #fa4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 20px #952;
}
.container form{
    display: none;
}
.container .text1{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #a8ac4e;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}
.container #exit{
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #a8ac4e;
    margin-left: 340px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float: right;
}
.container #post{
    display: none;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: auto;
}
input:checked ~ form{
    display: block;
}
form header{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fe7;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 70px 0 20px 0;
    float: inherit;
    text-align: center;
}
#rate-1:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "I hate it! ";
}
#rate-2:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "I don't like it! ";
}
#rate-3:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "Is it awesome! ";
}
#rate-4:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "I just like it! ";
}
#rate-5:checked ~ form header:before{
    content: "I love it! ";
}
form .textarea{
    width: 325px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
form .textarea textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: lavender;
    font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
    resize: none;

}
.textarea textarea:focus{
    border-color: rgb(233, 230, 47);
}
form #btn1{
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 15px 0 15px 100px;
}
form #btn1 button{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #00997a;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Heebo", sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
form #btn1 button:hover{
    background: #1b1b1b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page smecher</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@500;700&family=Lobster&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
              <div id="post">
                <div id="exit">EDIT</div>
                <div class="text1">Thank you for rating us!</div>
              </div>
              <div id="star-widget">
                <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate-5">
                <label for="rate-5" class="fas fa-star"></label>
                <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate-4">
                <label for="rate-4" class="fas fa-star"></label>
                <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate-3">
                <label for="rate-3" class="fas fa-star"></label>
                <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate-2">
                <label for="rate-2" class="fas fa-star"></label>
                <input type="radio" name="rate" id="rate-1">
                <label for="rate-1" class="fas fa-star"></label>
                <script src="js/java2.js"></script>
                <form action="#">
                  <header></header>
                  <div class="textarea">
                    <textarea cols="30" placeholder="Describe your experience..."></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div id="btn1">
                    <button onClick='H()' type="submit">Post</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            </body>
```

I'm sorry if something is hard coding, or hard to understand, i'm a little tired. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Your code calls `cho` first and then calls `Haha` after 10000ms

Comment: Why not use a promise?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `setTimeout` is asynchronous:

```js
console.log("Before setTimeout");
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("In setTimeout");
}, 1000);
console.log("After setTimeout");
```

In other words, code inside setTimeout will execute later, but code after will not.

A solution in your current case would be to call `cho` in the `setTimeout`:

```js
setTimeout(function Haha() {
  widget.style.display = "none";
  post.style.display = "block";
  z = false;
  cho();
}, 10000);

function cho() {
  widget.style.display = "block";
  post.style.display = "none";
  x[0].checked = false;
  x[1].checked = false;
  x[2].checked = false;
  x[3].checked = false;
  x[4].checked = false;
  y[0].checked = false;
  y[1].checked = false;
  y[2].checked = false;
  y[3].checked = false;
  y[4].checked = false;
  z = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work :( I have a button, and i want to change the widget and post styles different from what my function cho does. But when i pressed it, my function is still there and after few second, my function cho is still working

Comment: we need more code to see what you wanna achieve

Comment: I edited now my post. Sorry for your time loss :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("Before setTimeout");
setTimeout(function() {
    Haha();
}, 1000);
function Haha() {
console.log("Start Haha");
//  widget.style.display = "none";
//  post.style.display = "block";
  z = false;
  setTimeout(function() {
    cho();
    setTimeout(function() {
    done();
}, 1000);
}, 10000);
}
function cho() {
console.log("Start cho");
//  widget.style.display = "block";
//  post.style.display = "none";
//  x[0].checked = false;
//  x[1].checked = false;
//  x[2].checked = false;
//  x[3].checked = false;
//  x[4].checked = false;
//  y[0].checked = false;
//  y[1].checked = false;
//  y[2].checked = false;
//  y[3].checked = false;
//  y[4].checked = false;
  z = false;
}
function done(){
console.log("After setTimeout");
}
```

Note: Unquote all of the lines with //